# How to order nested array of objects by their createdAt field in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following data in firebase:

```
{
 items: [
    { 
      title: 'Some title 1',
      createAt: 1630359921518
    },
    { 
      title: 'Some title 2',
      createAt: 1630359921518
    },
 ]
 
}
```

I want to order these **items** them by their createAt date. How can I a query it? Thanks

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You cannot get a single field from a document at first place. You would have to get the document and then sort is using Javascript. Another option would be to store those array elements in a sub-collection so you can order them by `createdAt` field and also limit number of results to be fetched.